# For Vector Spaces $V$ and $W$ with one Infinite Dimensional , is $\operatorname{Hom}(V, W)$ Isomorphic to $\operatorname{Hom}(W, V)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, infinity

If $V$ and $W$ are both finite then clearly $\operatorname{Dim} (\operatorname{Hom}(V, W)) = \operatorname{Dim}(V)\cdot\operatorname{Dim(W)} = \operatorname{Dim}(\operatorname{Hom}(W, V))$ so they are isomorphic.

I'm not so sure if one is infinite. An "infinite matrix" construction for a linear transformation from $V$ to $W$ would have $\operatorname{Dim}(V)$ rows each with a finite number of non-zero entries, while from $W$ to $V$ it would have $\operatorname{Dim}(W)$ rows each with a finite number of non-zero entries. This suggests that perhaps $\operatorname{Dim} (\operatorname{Hom}(V, W))\ne \operatorname{Dim}(\operatorname{Hom}(W, V))$ ?

Comment: Indeed, if $V$ is finite dimensional and $W$ is not, then those are not isomorphic. For example, if $W$ is infinite dimensional then $W^*$ has strictly larger dimension.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft. Thanks for the response. For $Dim(W)$ infinite then $W^*$ = $Hom(W, F)$ and $Dim(W^*)$ = $|F|^{Dim(W)} \gt Dim(W)$. Is it correct that $Dim(Hom(F, W) = Dim(W)$ ?

Comment: Yes. In fact, it is fairly easy to find an explicit isomorphism for that last one.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft P.S. And if both are infinite dimensional, not necessarily the same cardinality  ?

Comment: Obviously, if they have the same dimension (whether or not it is infinite), then the Hom-spaces will be isomorphic. If their dimensions differ, then I don't think the Hom-spaces will be isomorphic, but I have a feeling this might end up getting tangled into some continuum hypothesis stuff, so I am not sure.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft. Many thanks. If you would formulate your comments into an answer I would accept and close the question.